# Container's width adjustment for different devices

Tags: css

I am working on forums and want to make it responsive.

I have kept container's `width` as `800px`.

What should the `min-width` and `max-width` be in media queries so that it will work on all devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your CSS layout to work on all devices use [Fluid-Fluid-Fluid CSS layout](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-33-fluid-fluid-fluid/).

Example:

Instead of writing:

```
     width:800px;
```

you can use:

```
     width:78%;
```